# Exam pratice sample with matrices and recursion

Tags: java, recursion, multidimensional-array, matrix

This is a question from a past exam (Programming fundamentals), that I have no idea how to solve (after more than 2 hours trying):

Program a method `void fillingSumOfNeighbours(int[][]m)` that, assuming that m is a matrix in which the last column and line are already filled (non-zeros), fill the remaining values with the sum `m[i][j]=m[i][j+1]+m[i+1][j]+m[i+1][j+1]`. This method must be recursive!

So far I can fill the matrix the correct way, but can't make the recursion finite without using a field counter (doesn't seem correct to me because using a field counter to put a stop to the recursion requires a defined class). Is there a way to define the number of times a direct recursive method should run only within that method?

Basically it should do this:

```
_ _ 1
_ _ 1
1 1 1 

_ _ 1
_ 3 1
1 1 1

_ 5 1
_ 3 1
1 1 1

_ 5 1
5 3 1 
1 1 1

13 5 1
5  3 1
1  1 1
```

Comment: Just so you know, "more than 2 hours trying" isn't *that* impressive. Some problems take days, months, .. even *generations*!! Well, anyway - i recommend good ole P&P - paper-pen .. But 2 hours is a good minimum I must say ;)

Comment: Although I'm new to programming I'm not new to problems (I'm in my masters). I'm not saying that to be impressive. I'm saying that so that people can gauge my level of understanding/noob (and adjust the answers) by knowing the time it took for an x difficulty question.

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you fill in the WHOLE array on each recursive call. That seems like a lot of repeated work.

Comment: You're right. I just chose this way because the exam is on paper with pen (without computer) and I minimize my errors this way.

Comment: The way I read the question, it is asking you to fill in one row and one column of the array for each recursive call. It's not stated clearly, but seems to be implied, that you should send a smaller array each time you call the method recursively. If you do this, then you can easily make a base case to stop the recursion based on the size of the array.

Comment: Using recursion for this problem is silly -- there's nothing inherently recursive about the problem. Try solving it without as a benchmark.

Comment: The primary problem with your solution is that the "recursive" solution isn't really recursive. You are solving the problem iteratively.

Comment: @duskwuff If you look at the first 4 lines of the method, the OP *has* solved the problem non-recursively.

Comment: Are you allowed to create additional methods to solve the problem?

Comment: So how should I proceed. No additional methods.

Answer (score 2):

By seeing your example and problem statement, it's pretty clear that, you need to run 3 recursion: -

- One for moving vertical upwards
- One for moving horizontally left
- And one for diagonally left.

So, to manage that movement, you would have to pass the indices to your method as well. I hope you are allowed to modify the method.

So, basically your recursive call will be like this: -

```
fill(arr, row - 1, col);
fill(arr, row, col - 1);
fill(arr, row - 1, col - 1);
```

Assuming `fill` is your method that takes 3 parameters: -

- `int[][] arr`
- `int row`
- `int col`

Now, the first call as you can see is decreasing the row value, thus moving the index upwards. The second call is moving towards left. And the last call will be needed to cover the `top-left` most index.

And inside your method, you just have to write the logic to fill the current index you passed, using your formula. And yes, don't forget the base condition, i.e., when either index is less than 0, then return immediately.

So, this is how your method looks like: -

```
public static void fill(int[][] arr, int row, int col) {
    arr[row][col] = arr[row][col + 1] + arr[row + 1][col] + arr[row + 1][col + 1];
    if (row <= 0 || col <= 0) {
        return;
    }
    fill(arr, row - 1, col);
    fill(arr, row, col - 1);
    fill(arr, row - 1, col - 1);
}
```

And initial invocation would be like: -

```
fill(arr, row - 2, col - 2);
```

Where `row` is maximum row size and `col` is maximum col size.

Comment: Just a suggestion...Your solution seems pretty nice. But He could also use counter and give recursive call to those methods with if conditions to modify array with row and column indexes. It will look more weird but will give true essence of recursion.

Comment: I don't know what counter you are talking about, but in the method I posted, you can assume the `row` and `col` to be counter only, based on whose value I we have the base condition, and on the other hand, running parallel recursion back to back. You might be familiar with these kinds of recursion while coding for `merge sort` and `quick sort`. So, I don't really understand what is the definition of your true essense of recursion.

Comment: What I was thinking was call method only once and let the methods do its job like manipulating rows and columns with if condition. when count reaches at 4 then break recursion.

Comment: @smit.. Actually this problem is not the ideal fit for just one recursive call. Because this is basically `divide-and-conquer` kind of problem, just like a `merge sort`. The complete problem is itself divided into two major steps, as I have explained. One moving up, and one moving left. So, you have to work them out separately, and then ultimately you reach the final result. What you are saying is true for basic recursion. But it all depends upon what the problems specifies.

Comment: `int count = 0;
public static void fill(int[][] arr, int row, int col) {
        count++;
 if(count == 1){
    row = row - 1;
 } else if(count == 2){
           col = col - 1;
        } else if (count == 3){
           row = row - 1;
           col = col - 1;
        } else{
           return;
        }
    arr[row][col] = arr[row][col + 1] + arr[row + 1][col] + arr[row + 1][col + 1];
  
    fill(arr, row, col);
   
}` This is what I was thinking. It no different than yours and has one flaw about counter.

Comment: @smit.. Hmm. I think you would have to reset the `count` value to `0` also, at some place. But trust me, the one I posted is more clear and depicts ones intent more clearly. The multiple if-else condition here might be confusing on first view as to what is the exact logic followed and why have you checked condition for those 3 values of count only?

Comment: I am completely agree that your answer make sense and I am also skeptic about counter thats why I wrote _"has one flaw about counter"_, My only intent was to show  that this could be done in more basic recursion call

Comment: I love your solution but notice that the method can only have one parameter which is the array. So your solution doesn´t apply.

Answer (score 1):

```
preencheComSomaVizinhos (int[][]m){
    get(m,0,0)
}
get(int[][]m, int i, int j){
    if(!(i == m.length-1 || j==m.length-1)){
        m[i][j] = get(m, i, j+1) + get(m,i+1,j)+get(m,i+1,j+1);

    }
    return m[i][j]; 
}
```

Comment: if(m[i][j]==Integer.MIN_VALUE)? It only recurses if m[i][j] == -2,147,483,648?

Comment: The method being recursive with the exclamation point and all, is from the question of the exam.

Comment: It must be a void method, so you cannot return the array.

Answer (score 0):

I'd write it to recurse on the row and column number, with a base case when you are at the last row. If the array is square, you only need one recursion parameter (I'll assume this is the case).

Part way through the recursion, you have a situation like this:

```
0 0 0 0 0 *
0 x + + + *  <- currently working on row k
0 - & & & *
0 - & & & *
0 - & & & *
* * * * * *
```

The `*`s are already filled before you begin. You then call the recursive function with parameter `k+1`, which fills in all the cells marked `&`. You then have to manually fill in the row marked with `+`s, the column marked with `-`s, and the single cell on the corner marked `x`. Then you pass back control to the function that called you, which will fill in the rest of the cells marked `0`.

I haven't really written Java for a year, excuse my sloppy syntax!

```
void fillNeighbours(int[][] m) {

  int size = m.length;

  run(m, size, 0);  

}

void run(int[][] m, size, row) {

  if (row < size) {

    // fill the rest of the rows and cols
    run(m, size, row+1)

    // fill the column and row for this iteration
    for (int i = 1; size-i > row; i++) {
      m[row][size-i] = m[row+1][size-i] + m[row][size-i+1];
      m[size-i][row] = m[size-i+1][row] + m[size-i][row+1];
    }

    // fill the corner cell
    m[row][row] = m[row+1][row] + m[row][row+1];

  } else {
    // Base case, do nothing
  } 

}
```

Comment: You can only use one method and it can only have one parameter.